# Resolve custom domain name in local network

Tags: nginx, dns, bind9

I have an ubuntu 16.04 machine running nginx server. It serves an web app and every pc in my network can access the web app by typing the ip `192.168.0.31` in browser. How can I make a custom name like `mydomain.local` resolved to this ip?

All the pcs and laptops including the server in my network are connected in a mikrotik router. I have looked up methods to setup local dns server using bind9 but that's not quite working for me. An step by step guideline could be a great help for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your workstations are configured to use Mikrotik router as their DNS server, you can go to MT Webfig, IP, DNS, Static, and add an entry there.

Comment: https://youtu.be/SATEOZwjw4U
Hope this helps. As you are using it on the local network.

Comment: My problem was solved by putting the IP of the DNS server in the routers of my network. Thank you for your response

Comment: Thank you for your response. It turned out i configured bind9 correctly. I just had to put the IP of the DNS server in the routers of my network.